# Conversion of Java code to PHP - loss of significant digits in php while performing mathematical operations on double numbers

Tags: java, php

I am trying to convert some logic written in Java to PHP, and seeing different output in PHP while performing mathematical operations on double-precision numbers than java.

See below code and outputs

```
    --------- java --------------
    double x =  0.1*(double)37.17;
    System.out.print(x); // prints 3.7170000000000005  

    --------- PHP --------------
    $x =  0.1*(double)37.17;
    echo $x; // prints 3.717
```

Why is this occurring? When I use these values in some logarithmic operations it makes significant differences in the result.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not the arithmetic per se.  The problem is that by default PHP outputs floating point numbers with two digits after the decimal point.

You can change this (default) with `ini_set`; i.e.

```
ini_set('precision', 17);
```

Alternatively, you can use `format_number` to convert the number to a string, and control the number of digits after the decimal directly.  Or use `printf`.

For more information:

- https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2013/06/the-php-floating-point-precision-is-wrong-by-default/
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php

Comment: Also the [php.net page for floating point numbers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) mention a _Warning_ about this (like you said) and suggest using "[arbitrary precision math functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php) and [gmp](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.gmp.php)" but the `precision` ini setting appears to be good!

Comment: The OP is comparing floating-point in Java and PHP.  If floating-point is good enough in Java, then it should be in PHP as well.  The OP just needs to know how to do it (i.e. format numbers) in PHP.  Arbitrary precision is most likely over-kill.

Answer (score 1):

> They like 3.7170000000000005 or 37.17.

**By default, doubles print with the minimum number of decimal places needed on PHP.**

---

But do you need the exact answer,try

**Understand the basics of Floating Point**

> Rewrite the code like this You can change `18f` to what you wish.

```
$x = 0.1*37.17;
echo $x; // prints 3.717  

printf("%4.18f", $x)
```